# A disk with center at $(x_0,y_0)$ and density function of $ln(x^2+y^2)$ has an average density $ln(x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^{2})$?

Tags: calculus

I came across a conclusion that a disk, not passing the origin $(0,0)$, with center at $(x_0,y_0)$ and density function of $ln(x^2+y^2)$ has an average density $ln(x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^{2})$.
It seems rather difficult to do the integral directly. And it seems also difficult to find the symmetry. For example, $(x_0,y_0)$ has distance $R$ from the origin and the radius of the disk is $r$. Then $ln(x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^{2})$ is $2lnR$. But take the two points have the distance $R-r$ and $R+r$, the sum of density of them is $2ln(R^2-r^2)$, it is not concerned with $2lnR$ so much? Can you please proove it?

Comment: With regard to calculating the integral, you can probably make use of the substitution $r^2=x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2)$ is harmonic ($\triangle f=0$) in every domain not containing $(0,0)$. As such, it has the [mean value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property), that is:
$$
{1\over \pi r^2}\int f(x,y)dxdy= f(x_0,y_0),
$$
where the integration is carried out on a circle of radius $r$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$, provided the origin is outside the circle.